# Is there a way to place a keyboard shortcut inside an editable div?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, i have a div which users can type into it. i would like to place shortcuts so when the user inputs the word pi. The output would be the symbol π. Or if the user inputs sqrt then they would get this symbol inf then the output would be ∞. and even when the tab button is clicked to indent a couple of lines. I have not seen a web app that does this yet so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's some extensive key tracking + field updating you can do to accomplish this, or you can get a jQuery plugin that already does something similar (if not exactly) and modify it to accomplish the same task.

This might be what you are looking for though:
http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/wiki/about

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a replace. See [JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/bFurj/4/)

```
$('.test').keydown(function (event) {
  if ($('.test').val().contains("pi")) {
    var newVal = $('.test').val().replace("pi", "π");
    $('.test').val(newVal);
    //Place Cusor at the end of the div if using editable div
  }
  else if ($('.test').val().contains("inf")) {
    var newVal = $('.test').val().replace("inf", "∞");
    $('.test').val(newVal);
    //Place Cusor at the end of the div if using editable div
  }
});
```

In this sample I am using an `input`. You can change that to `div`